# Using transaction and simple DB connection in the same struct because of this pattern what can I do?

Tags: database, go, transactions, go-gorm, go-pg

I found [a great example of transactions between Repositories](https://github.com/agungdwiprasetyo/agungdpcms/blob/master/src/resume/usecase/usecase_impl.go#L77) using a Clean Architecture approach.

This guy is using [Gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm).

Gorm has the same type for a DB connection and a transaction, example:

```golang
var db *gorm.DB
var tx *gorm.DB
```

I'm a fan of [`go-pg`](https://github.com/go-pg/pg). But here the types are different (maybe it's even better as is), example:

```golang
var db *pg.DB
var tx *pg.Tx
```

And of course the error is: `Cannot use 'tx' (type *Tx) as type *pg.DB`

A small reproduction:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-pg/pg/v10"
)

type Player struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

type PlayerRepo struct {
    db       *pg.DB
    teamRepo *TeamRepo
}

type TeamRepo struct {
    db *pg.DB
}

func NewPlayerRepo(db *pg.DB) *PlayerRepo {
    return &PlayerRepo{
        db:       db,
        teamRepo: NewTeamRepo(db),
    }
}

func NewTeamRepo(db *pg.DB) *TeamRepo {
    return &TeamRepo{db: db}
}

func (r *PlayerRepo) Find(id int) (*Player, error) {
    var player Player
    err := r.db.Model(&player).Where("id = ?", id).Select()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &player, nil
}

func (r *PlayerRepo) All() ([]*Player, error) {
    // Long code
    return nil, nil
}

func (r *PlayerRepo) Insert() (*Player, error) {
    // Long code
    return nil, nil
}

func (r *PlayerRepo) Update() (*Player, error) {
    // Long code
    return nil, nil
}

func (r *PlayerRepo) Delete() (*Player, error) {
    // Long code
    return nil, nil
}

func (r *PlayerRepo) WithTransaction(txFunc func(*PlayerRepo) error) (err error) {
    tx, _ := r.db.Begin()
    manager := NewPlayerRepo(tx) // <<<--- here the problem! tx is not good here, it's `pg.Tx` not `pg.DB`
    err = txFunc(manager)
    return
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance. ❤️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an interface that is already, implicitly implemented by both:

```golang
type DB interface {
    Begin() (*Tx, error)
    Close() error
    Context() context.Context
    CopyFrom(r io.Reader, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (res Result, err error)
    CopyTo(w io.Writer, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (res Result, err error)
    Exec(query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    ExecContext(c context.Context, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    ExecOne(query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    ExecOneContext(c context.Context, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    Formatter() orm.QueryFormatter
    Model(model ...interface{}) *orm.Query
    ModelContext(c context.Context, model ...interface{}) *orm.Query
    Prepare(q string) (*Stmt, error)
    Query(model interface{}, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    QueryContext(c context.Context, model interface{}, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    QueryOne(model interface{}, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    QueryOneContext(c context.Context, model interface{}, query interface{}, params ...interface{}) (Result, error)
    RunInTransaction(ctx context.Context, fn func(*Tx) error) error
}
```

*NOTE: I only know that the method names match, I didn't bother checking if the signatures also do, if they don't, you'll need to edit the interface accordingly.*

You can add a simple "compiler check":

```golang
var _ DB = (*pg.DB)(nil)
var _ DB = (*pg.Tx)(nil)
```

And then you can change the type of the `PlayerRepo.db` field from `*pg.DB` to your new `DB` interface.

```golang
type PlayerRepo struct {
    db       DB
    teamRepo *TeamRepo
}

type TeamRepo struct {
    db DB
}

func NewPlayerRepo(db DB) *PlayerRepo {
    return &PlayerRepo{
        db:       db,
        teamRepo: NewTeamRepo(db),
    }
}

func NewTeamRepo(db DB) *TeamRepo {
    return &TeamRepo{db: db}
}


func (r *PlayerRepo) WithTransaction(txFunc func(*PlayerRepo) error) (err error) {
    tx, err := r.db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        // rollback if err; commit if no err
    }()
    manager := NewPlayerRepo(tx)
    err = txFunc(manager)
    return
}
```

---

If your repo types need to be able to invoke some of the methods that are *not* common to both `pg.DB` and `pg.Tx`, and therefore not defined by the new `DB` interface, then, one approach would be to retain the original types for such use, for example:

```golang
type PlayerRepo struct {
    db       DB
    pg       *pg.DB
    teamRepo *TeamRepo
}

type TeamRepo struct {
    db DB
    pg *pg.DB
}

func NewPlayerRepo(db DB, pg *pg.DB) *PlayerRepo {
    return &PlayerRepo{
        db:       db,
        pg:       pg,
        teamRepo: NewTeamRepo(db, pg),
    }
}

func NewTeamRepo(db DB, pg *pg.DB) *TeamRepo {
    return &TeamRepo{db: db, pg: pg}
}

func (r *PlayerRepo) WithTransaction(txFunc func(*PlayerRepo) error) (err error) {
    tx, err := r.db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        // rollback if err; commit if no err
    }()
    manager := NewPlayerRepo(tx, r.pg)
    err = txFunc(manager)
    return
}
```

---

Note that if you decide to use `orm.DB`, which is reasonable, but it is missing some of the methods that you need and that are already implemented by both `pg.DB` and `pg.Tx`, then you could embed `orm.DB` into your custom interface and add only those methods that are missing.

```golang
type DB interface {
    Begin() (*Tx, error)
    orm.DB
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think I found `orm.DB` interface. But still I need a lot of code in my methods to check with type assertion if is `pg.Tx` or `pg.DB`.

Comment: I found a way with the code here: https://github.com/go-pg/pg/issues/1770#issuecomment-720080030. What do you think about?

Comment: @FredHors `Being` is implemented by both `pg.DB` and `pg.Tx`, and if it is not implemented by `orm.DB` then use a custom interface, why, if you don't have to, would you rather resort to type switches or reflection?

Comment: oh wow I didn't know this. Does Type assertion use `reflection` in background? Is not a native in-language feature?

Comment: I don't wanna create a DB custom interface my self because I want to write as little code as possible. And maybe I need other methods too other than `Begin`.

Comment: @FredHors I never said type assertion uses reflection, I said "*or* reflection" and I did so only because it is often used for the same thing for which type assertion is. *"I don't wanna create a DB custom interface my self because I want to write as little code as possible."* you are forgetting that declaring a custom interface allows you to omit all the type assertions that you will have to invoke every time if you keep using an insufficient interface which will result in significantly more code, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @FredHors I've added to the bottom of my answer an example of how to embed interfaces which allows you to not have to enumerate all the methods that are already present in the library's own code.

Comment: Wow. You're a genius! it works very good! Thanks a lot! Now the problem is I don't know in my method if this transaction is method scoped (so I can rollback or commit it here in method) or is `WithTransaction()` usecase's scoped (and I need to return simply an error or nil). What do you suggest to detect this?

Comment: Now the error is: `"pg: transaction has already been committed or rolled back"`.

Comment: @FredHors That error means that you're comitting or rolling back and already comited or rolled back transaction. You would get that error regardless of whether you use the interface or the concrete `pg.Tx` type.

Comment: @FredHors note also that you're asking about an error, caused by some code, that you have not shared, it is therefore impossible for me to accurately and precisely pinpoint what it is that you're doing wrong.